# ASP.NET ScriptService prevent return of null properties in JSON

Tags: asp.net, service

Basically I want to make my script service only serialise properties that are not null on an array of object I am returning...  So this..

{"k":"9wjH38dKw823","s":10,"f":null,"l":null,"j":null,"p":null,"z":null,"i":null,"c":null,"m":0,"t":-1,"u":2}

would be

{"k":"9wjH38dKw823","s":10,"m":0,"t":-1,"u":2}

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Basically the reason for this is because null values are for unchanged properties.  A local copy is kept in the javascript that is just updated to reduce traffic to the server.  Change values are then merged.

Comment: What kind of object are you using that has these properties?  Is it a particular class?  Dictionary<string, string>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class for the JSON serialization process to use to handle your object, and then put the necessary logic in the Serialize method of that class to exclude the properties that are null.

[This article](http://nayyeri.net/custom-json-serialization-in-asp-net-ajax) has a clear step-by-step discussion of the process involved in creating it.

You probably would not need to actually implement the Deserialize method (can throw a NotImplementedException) if you are not passing that type of object in as an input parameter to your web services.

Comment: This did the job perfectly thank you.  Its also useful for some other issues too.